# Columnstore Rowgroup Few Rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, columnstore

I have a table that has ~43M rows. For internal purposes we need to create an clustered columnstore index on this table. For such purposes we use the following command.

```
CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX CCI_tblName ON dbo.tblName
WITH (MAXDOP = 1)
```

However, from some reason the row groups are too small as you can see on the image below.

[image]

What can be cause of this? As far as I know, the minimum size of row group is 102,400 rows therefore I do not understand how come these row groups are that small.

There are `775 row groups` created for that table in total.

---

Update #1 - checking the `sys.dm_db_column_store_row_group_physical_stats` stats, the trim reasons are mostly caused by `DICTIONARY_SIZE`. How to handle this situation?

Comment: How much memory available to SQL Server? IIRC, the target row group size is 1M rows but will be reduced when there's not enough memory available.

Comment: It seems to be problem with dictionary_size, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2014/05/03/clustered-column-store-factors-that-impact-size-of-a-rowgroup/ .

Comment: Did you check `sys.dm_db_column_store_row_group_physical_stats` to see if `DICTIONARY_SIZE` is the reason? If so, post the results of that query as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A possible problem might be that your server is low on memory.

> his blog post is focusing on one of the most important real world
>   issues – Memory Pressure. While testing on your own Computer or on
>   some development server in a controlled environment, most of the time,
>   if not always, you are not hitting any limits. There are no hundreds
>   of simultaneous connections bombing your server with requests and
>   there are no queries taking away all of your available buffer pool
>   memory.
>
> I have executed a couple of tests recently and while experimenting
>   with the maximum memory settings to show the Spill process, I totally
>   forgot to reset it to the original value and so while trying to
>   rebuild a Clustered Columnstore Index, I was surprised with quite
>   distinct values as the maximum size of the Row Groups that I was
>   getting. This blog post is about diving into some of details that I
>   have discovered since.

Source: http://www.nikoport.com/2014/06/21/clustered-columnstore-indexes-part-31-memory-pressure-and-row-group-sizes/

Also, you might have some white characters unseen in the results of the queries, making a difference between seemingly similar values, hence different groups. You will need to investigate this as well.